# How can I disable SFTP so that FTP is the only daemon open?

Tags: sftp

In `sshd_config` I've commented out:

`Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server`

but `sftp` is still working. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Port 22 is SSH/scp/[SFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol). Port 21 is ftp. `vsftpd` handles FTP/[FTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS), not SFTP. They are different protocols, and everything is like it's meant to be.